# Error shown while running Javascript game

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in learning JavaScript and currently in the process of building a classic game of snakes. I keep pushing my code to git in small changes since that way it becomes easier to track where the issue is happening.

So now I see the below error on the console when i run my game on localhost.

[image: ref2]

and on click of the error on console, i get taken to

[image: ref1]

There is no syntax error which I am sure so it must be some semantics i am going wrong about here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my .js file I suspect might be causing the issue

<kbd>snakes.js</kbd>

```
import { getInputDirection } from "./input";

export const SNAKE_SPEED = 1; //Controls the speed of the snake;
const snakeBody = [
  { x: 10, y: 11 },
  { x: 11, y: 11 },
  { x: 12, y: 11 },
];

export function update() {
  const inputDirection = getInputDirection();
  for (let i = snakeBody.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    snakeBody[i + 1] = { ...snakeBody[i] };
  }
  snakeBody[0].x += inputDirection.x;
  snakeBody[0].y += inputDirection.y;
}

export function draw(gameBoard) {
  snakeBody.forEach((segment) => {
    const snakeElement = document.createElement("div");
    snakeElement.style.gridRowStart = segment.y;
    snakeElement.style.gridColumnStart = segment.x;
    snakeElement.classList.add("snake");
    gameBoard.appendChild(snakeElement);
  });
}
```

<kbd>input.js</kbd>

```
let inputDirection = { x: 0, y: 0 };

export function getInputDirection() {
  return inputDirection;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is simple. You have an error with importing your `input.js` in `snakes.js` here.

**Change**

```
import { getInputDirection } from "./input";
```

**To**

```
import { getInputDirection } from "./input.js";
```

Comment: Okay so we need to include the .js extension?

Comment: Yeah that's why you are seeing the error. Try it and check back